# How to use pandas chunk for large data into split the data for x_train and y_train for machine learning?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

df_chunk=pd.read_csv(filename,chunk=1000)
X_train,Y_train,X_test,Y_test=train_test.split(df_chunk)

How to use df_chunk into splitting it for x and y train data

Answer (score 0):

I've never come across this before. Maybe you can try this.

https://examples.dask.org/machine-learning/incremental.html

Or, this.

https://zerowithdot.com/splitting-to-batches/

Or, get a fraction of your original data set. If it's truly random, a sample should be fairly representative of the overall data set.

```
# Fraction of rows
# here you get .50 % of the rows
df.sample(frac = 0.5)
```